# Does Frame Rate choice make a difference when rendering animations as individual images?

Tags: animation, output

I have been rendering animations as single PNG images and then importing them into an external video editor to create videos. Does the Blender Frame Rate setting make a difference in how the frames are rendered? Are 1800 frames rendered at 30 fps the same as 1800 frames rendered at 60 fps? Does Frame Rate affect how motion blur or Composite post-processing effects are applied? Thanks. Blender 3.10, Windows 11

Answer (score 6):

I am pretty sure it doesnt.
I mean, fps is just a measurement for videos, so you actually can "set" your own fps when you combine the pictures.
On the other hand, it seems smart to set the fps equivalent to the end result, so that you can watch your animations in real time inside blender.

Comment: Yep, for animation previews within Blender it makes sense to set the fps to whatever you want the final output to be. ThankS!